# What is the use of "arguments[0]" when implementing javascriptexecutor?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have implemented successfully `JavascriptExecutor` but I want to know why we take this array "`arguments[0]`"?

Here is the code below:

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(locator));
```

Comment: It appears to be running in the context of an anonymous function which is getting passed whatever `driver.FindElement(locator)` produces. So, `arguments[0]` is your way of accessing the first argument to the anonymous function.

Comment: Just consider it as a command line arguments for your script.

Comment: Okay, i got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the definition from [Selenium ExecuteScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) page

> The arguments will be made available to the JavaScript via the "arguments" magic variable, as if the function were called via "Function.apply"

and the returning value of executeScript is:

> Returns:
>   One of Boolean, Long, String, List or WebElement. Or null.

which means that returning object is a list and you can interact with by `arguments[0]` magic variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to the arguments you pass in. In this case the index is 0 because you're passing in the element reference as the 0th argument in the executeScript call (the parameter after the String containing the script).