# Not able to click on the div tag element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on the 'Admin' tab. 
The html code is as follows

```
<div id="TransactionLinksTabContainer">
      <ul class="TransactionLinksTab listitem-cursor-pointer" id="ctl00_PostIssueContent_PostIssueTrxLinks_TransactionTabsList">
         <li><div>Transactions</div></li>
         <li><div>Restricted</div></li>
         <li><div>Quotes</div></li>
         <li><div>Admin</div></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this solution which did not work

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*   [@id='TransactionLinksTabContainer']/ul/li[4]/div[text()='Admin']")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Try `By.xpath("((//div[@id='TransactionLinksTabContainer']/ul/li)[4])/div");`

Comment: Thanks Jayesh.. But did not work

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, since you are clicking on the element, a more better condition would be `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`

Comment: I am not getting any error. The test passes. But after the element is clicked, there is  an list of options which appears. The next step is to click on one of the list. But the list is not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click on element using java-script executor method to click on element.

```
WebElement admin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ctl00_PostIssueContent_PostIssueTrxLinks_TransactionTabsList']/li/div[contains(text(), 'Admin')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", admin);
```

> OR 
> Use explicit wait method and then try to click on element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ctl00_PostIssueContent_PostIssueTrxLinks_TransactionTabsList']/li/div[contains(text(), 'Admin')]"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ctl00_PostIssueContent_PostIssueTrxLinks_TransactionTabsList']/li/div[contains(text(), 'Admin')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Java Script Executor worked. But can you explain me what does that Arguments[0] do?

Comment: This might will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669291/what-is-the-use-of-arguments0-when-implementing-javascriptexecutor?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You can use [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Axes/descendant) function as well for reaching to the required control, as shown below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='TransactionLinksTabContainer']/descendant::div[text()='Admin']")));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you to use

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='TransactionLinksTabContainer']/ul/li[4]/div[text()='Admin']")));
WebElement element = driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TransactionLinksTabContainer']/ul/li[4]/div[text()='Admin']"))
element.click();
```

I don't think that there is an issue with the XPath, it may be that "Wait element is not able to stored in an Webelement"